# Call a jquery function after .submit()

Tags: jquery, form-submit

I save the data on my DB. After i would display the new updated items calling the function "loadInitPosts()"
This is my code:

```
function post_save_ajax() {
    $(this).submit();
    loadInitPosts();
}

function loadInitPosts() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "home/loadInitPosts",
        success: function (data) {
            $(".posts").empty();
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            $(".posts").append(data);
        }
    });
}
```

The function loadInitPosts is correctly called, but display the old data. It seems that is called before submit execute his task.

Comment: Where is `post_save_ajax` called? What does `this` reference?

Comment: On my form i get the event onsubmit='post_save_ajax()'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(this).submit(function () {
    loadInitPosts();
});
```

Comment: This will have no effect if he hasn't cancelled the event that emits after submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
function post_save_ajax() {
$(this).submit( function(){
loadInitPosts();
event.preventDefault();
});

}

 function loadInitPosts() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "home/loadInitPosts",
    success: function (data) {
        $(".posts").empty();
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $(".posts").append(data);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: @AnielloCaputo use this:
    $(this).submit( function(){
    loadInitPosts();
    event.preventDefault();
    });